# Ionic2,Angular2: [(ngModel)] for ion-checkbox or html checkbox?

Tags: html, checkbox, ionic2, angular2-forms, persist

What should the [(ngModel)] in the following case be,such that I can persist the state of the checkbox in the slide ? I need to slide from one slide to another upon selecting the checkboxes but when I click previous the state needs to be persisted.

Here is what I've for radio buttons. I just changed the radio buttons code into checkbox but it is not working.So I removed the [value] property and now if I select one checkbox, all of them are getting checked.

```
    <ion-content padding>

      <ion-slides>
        <ion-slide *ngFor="let question of questions; let i = index">
          <h1>{{ question.text }}</h1>
           <span *ngIf="question.type=='singlecorrect'>
          <ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="question.answer">
            <ion-item no-lines no-padding *ngFor="let choice of question.choices">
              <ion-label>{{ choice.choiceText }}</ion-label>
              <ion-radio [value]="choice"></ion-radio>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-list>
          </span>

           <span *ngIf="question.type=='singlecorrect'>
          <ion-list checkbox-group [(ngModel)]="question.answer">
            <ion-item no-lines no-padding *ngFor="let choice of question.choices">
              <ion-label>{{ choice.choiceText }}</ion-label>
              <ion-checkbox></checkbox>  // ERROR : no value accessor found. 
            </ion-item>
          </ion-list>
          </span>

          <ion-row margin-top>
            <ion-col>
              <button (click)="showPrevious()" ion-button text-only [disabled]="i === 0" >Previous</button>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col>
              <button [disabled]="!question.answer" *ngIf="i < questions.length - 1" (click)="showNext()" ion-button text-only >Next</button>
              <button [disabled]="!question.answer" *ngIf="i === questions.length - 1" (click)="showNext()" ion-button text-only >Submit</button>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>

        </ion-slide>
      </ion-slides>

</ion-content>
```

I'm storing the selected choices in an array called "answer".Refer this:[Angular2,Typescript: How to put the radio button checked when in an array which displays one element per page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44455814/angular2-typescript-how-to-put-the-radio-button-checked-when-in-an-array-which)
Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if all questions should use checkboxes, or just some of them. I've modified the previous plunker to set some questions as a *multiple choice question* and left the rest as *single choice questions*. Please take a look at the **[new version of the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pdH9hPHQXdi9lNjctNVs?p=preview)**

This is the end result:

[image: ionic demo]

In the demo, now each question has the following properties:

```
 {
    text: 'Question 1',
    multiple: false,
    choices: [...],
    answer: null
  }
```

If the question allows multiple answers, then the `answer` property is initialized with an array, with one item per available choice of that question.

```
// Initialize the answers
this.questions.forEach(question => {
  if(question.multiple) {
    // Initialize an array with as many elements as the number of choices
    question.answer = new Array(question.choices.length);
  }
});
```

Then in the view we render radio items or checkbox items accordingly:

```
<ion-slides>
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let question of questions; let i = index">
      <h1>{{ question.text }}</h1>

        <!-- Single choice: radio items -->
        <div *ngIf="!question.multiple">
          <ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="question.answer">
            <ion-item no-lines no-padding *ngFor="let choice of question.choices">
              <ion-label>{{ choice.choiceText }}</ion-label>
              <ion-radio [value]="choice"></ion-radio>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-list>
        </div>

        <!-- Multiple choice: checkbox items -->
        <div *ngIf="question.multiple">
          <ion-item no-lines no-padding *ngFor="let choice of question.choices; let i = index">
            <ion-label>{{ choice.choiceText }}</ion-label>
            <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="question.answer[i]"></ion-checkbox>
          </ion-item>
        </div>


      <span style="font-size: 1.2rem;">Selected answer: {{ question.answer | json }}</span>

      <ion-row margin-top>
        <ion-col>
          <button (click)="showPrevious()" ion-button text-only [disabled]="i === 0" >Previous</button>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          <button [disabled]="!question.answer" *ngIf="i < questions.length - 1" (click)="showNext()" ion-button text-only >Next</button>
          <button [disabled]="!question.answer" *ngIf="i === questions.length - 1" (click)="showNext()" ion-button text-only >Submit</button>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>

    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You made my day! :)

Comment: I've a small doubt. How do I store the choices as Objects in the answer array ? Because I'll have to compare the choiceId with the right answer which I have as a field in my API called "right answers".Right now my answer array consists of only true or false. But what if I need to store the "choicId"

Comment: By using an array with as many items as the number of choices, if the answer array is `[true, null, true, null]` you can get the `choiceId` by using the index of the items set to true... so in that case, the selected choices Id would be `question.choices[0].id` and `question.choices[2].id` since the index 0 and 2 of the answer array are true.

Comment: I tried this in the .ts file but I got an error saying "cannot read property choiceId of undefined" 

for(i=0;i< question.answer.length:i++)
              {
                if( question.answer[i] !== '' ||  question.answer[i] !== false)
                console.log("Multicorrect" question.answer[i].choiceId);
              }

Comment: It's kind of difficult to read code from the comments. Could you please edit your question to include that last comment?

Comment: Hey sorry.My bad. I got it. I didn't see what you've given correctly. I've another requirement.If you don't mind can you please answer this:

I want to display the whole list of questions in the end and on click of that question I should be navigated to that particular slide of the question.Can you please tell me how to do it ?  Thanks a lot for all the help.